# Call app maker server script from Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-app-maker

I have an app-maker server-side script that I would like to be able to call from the client script, or from code in a Google Sheet. Is this possible? If not, what would be the best way to create code that can be called from an app maker client or a google sheet?

Comment: From the client you use `google.script.run.YourServerFunction()`. There is no API to call functions inside App Maker from other programs, so therefore it's not possible to call a function in App Maker from Google Sheets. The alternative would be to call your database via JCDB connection from Google Sheets to connect to the same database as what your AM application is using.